# Writing Flexable SQL SELECT Queries in VBA

Tags: mysql, vba

The general idea was to create a VBA script that effectively write SQL SELECT queries for users that don't have experience with SQL. It accepts from a database that they're already familiar with. The ultimate goal is to allow users to:

1. Select what columns they would like to see.
2. Make simple restrictions on them (date range, specific part numbers)
3. Order this list however they would like.

I have written (in VBA) a script to do so, but I have one remaining issue. I can't execute SELECT queries directly in VBA. I also can't find any information on how to export the completed query from VBA back into the Access Database. I've considered writing to a text file, then having Access read from said text file, using a macro, and importing the query, but it does not appear that Access support such a functionality..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*I can't execute SELECT queries directly in VBA*". Why not? Why can't you do that? What is preventing you from doing that?  http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3505836/Executing-SQL-Statements-in-VBA-Code.htm

Comment: Originally I was trying to use DoCMD.RunSQL, which doesn't (at least from my attempts/read) work with SELECT Queries. I did find a better solution though:

    Dim qryDEF As QueryDef
    Set qryDEF = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("UserQry", SQL)
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("UserQry")

The only extra that this needed was a line to delete the query when rerunning the code, which has the added benefit of requerying the data in the process. The module works as intended. Thanks to all who helped anyways!

If anyone has any questions though, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sql_ as String
    sql_ = "SELECT * FROM Table"

DoCmd.RunSQL sql_


Dim sql_ as String
    sql_ = "UPDATE Table SET Field = 'ABC'"

CurrentDb.Execute sql_, dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would tackle this myself:

1. Write the VBA to build the SQL string (which you've done)
2. Create a data connection to your Access DB (Data > Get External Data > From Access)
3. Use VBA to change the command text in the data connection properties, then refresh.

This should enable you to dynamically build SQL, query the DB and return the results to Excel in a table.

Hope that helps!